# golang initializing struct with embedded template: too few values in struct initializer

Tags: go

I'm trying to initialize a golang struct with an embedded template. Since templates have no fields, I would expect that assigning the correct number of variables to a constructor would work, but instead the compiler complains that

```
main.go:17:19: too few values in struct initializer

package main

import "fmt"

type TestTemplate interface {
    Name() string
}

type TestBase struct {
    name       string

    TestTemplate
}

func New(name string) *TestBase {
    return &TestBase{name} // This fails
    //return &TestBase{name: name} // This works
}

func (v *TestBase) Name() string {
    return v.name
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(New("Hello"))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types

An *embedded field* is still a *field*, the name of which is derived from its type, therefore `TestBase` has actually *two fields* and not one, namely `name` and `TestTemplate`.

This compiles just fine:

```
var t *TestBase
t.TestTemplate.Print()
```

So when initializing `TestBase` you either specify the field names or you initialize all fields.

These all compile:

```
_ = &TestBase{name, nil}
_ = &TestBase{name: name}
_ = &TestBase{name: name, TestTemplate: nil}
_ = &TestBase{TestTemplate: nil}
```

Comment: Ahh, I meant to define the template to have Name() rather than Print() but that's not too relevant to the problem. Thank you, I was thinking that the template wasn't a field and just told the compiler that this object should implement these functions.

Comment: Be careful when trying to fit traditional OOP concepts into Go. The Go language wasn't build for that. Embedding just tells the compiler that the `Print/Name` method can be *accessed directly* from `TestBase` without specifying the field to which it belongs, but the embedded type and it's method have no knowledge about the type inside which they are embedded, so the `Name/Print` method will not have access to the `TestBase.name` field.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (as far as general concepts go) you're confusing **interface**s with **composition** (which is kind of how Go approaches the whole `inheritance` question.

This post might be helpful for you: https://medium.com/@gianbiondi/interfaces-in-go-59c3dc9c2d98

So `TestTemplate` is an interface.

That means that the `struct` `TestBase` will *implement* the methods (whose signature is) defined in the interface.

You should implement `Print` for `TestBase`.

But in anycase the error you're getting is because when you initialize a struct with no field names specified, it expects all the field names to be entered, see

https://gobyexample.com/structs

So remove the `composition` `TestTemplate` from the struct (and implement the method defined in the interface instead), and it should work.

Also, FYI, the `Stringer` interface with `String` method is what `fmt.Println` expects to print an arbitrary struct (not a `Print` method) see: https://tour.golang.org/methods/17